# SQL: Need a formula that can look at previous row

Tags: sql, testing, boolean, formula

I've got a table with 3 columns: CarID, EventName, Timestamp.
Each row of the table tells wether a car has entered or exited a compound, with a corresponding timestamp to it.

When grouping and ordering this table by CarID and EventName, the table should not have 2 consecutive rows that have the same event. A car cannot enter the compound twice or exit it twice consecutively.

I need to have another column, which can check if this is true or false.

```
CarID    | EventNAme    | Timestamp
927      | Enter        | 2020-04-30
927      | Exit         | 2020-05-28
906      | Enter        | 2020-11-06
906      | Exit         | 2020-11-26
609      | Enter        | 2021-02-08
609      | Exit         | 2021-02-10
609      | Exit         | 2021-02-10
609      | Enter        | 2021-02-12
900      | Enter        | 2020-11-12
900      | Enter        | 2020-11-18
900      | Exit         | 2020-11-18
```

So I need to write something in SQL in such way, that the result of the table would be like below:

```
CarID    | EventNAme    | Timestamp    | Test
927      | Enter        | 2020-04-30   | True
927      | Exit         | 2020-05-28   | True
906      | Enter        | 2020-11-06   | True
906      | Exit         | 2020-11-26   | True
609      | Enter        | 2021-02-08   | True
609      | Exit         | 2021-02-10   | True
609      | Exit         | 2021-02-10   | False
609      | Enter        | 2021-02-12   | True
900      | Enter        | 2020-11-12   | True
900      | Enter        | 2020-11-18   | False
900      | Exit         | 2020-11-18   | True
```

With kind regards,

Lazzanova

Comment: You are asking for `LAG()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(eventname, 1, eventname) over (partition by car order by timestamp) = eventname
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as test
from t;
```

EDIT:

If the default parameter is not supported by your database, ten just use `coalesce`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when coalesce(lag(eventname) over (partition by car order by timestamp), eventname) = eventname
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as test
from t;
```

Comment: I'm getting the message: ERROR: Default parameter not be supported for window function lag when using your statement above.

Comment: @Lazzanova . . . That's odd.  It is standard SQL and almost all databases support it.